# Battery issues in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, power-management, battery

**Hello**
I have a dual boot system and Ubuntu 20.04 is intalled. So today my laptop charging was around 60% and suddenly it was showing 100% and after 10 minutes it was again 56%. It does not happen every time and doesn't happen in Windows 10 so is there any way to calibrate the battery level if this happen. Is this a serious problem ?